# Concatenate two integers in php

Tags: php

I know it is possible in php to concatenate two strings like

```
$a .= $b;
```

which is equal to

```
$a = $a . $b;
```

Is it possible to do something with integers? but with math operations? I have two variables:

```
$var1 = 8;
$var2 = 2;
```

I need to do `$var1 - $var2`, but I don't want to create third variable to hold this calculation. I would try `$var1 = $var1 + $var2` will this work? Is there another `.=` similar way of doing it?

Comment: Do you want to _add_ `$var2` to `$var1`, or concatenate (`4+2=6` vs. `4 . 2 = 42`)? Just: _every_ binary operators can get combined with the assigment-operator `=` (`-=`, `|=`, `>>=`, ...)

Comment: As KingCruch implies, concatenation is not the same as addition.

Comment: @KingCrunch yes I was asking for short form, sorry for confusing post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in C and C++, PHP supports `Compound_assignment_operators`:

So, the line:
`$var1 = $var1 + $var2;`

is equivalent to:
`$var1 += $var2;`

For full list of those operators, take a look at [Compound_assignment_operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators)

Comment: why this is the corect  answer , the question is asking about  concatenate two integers , and your solution will add not concatenate. 
it should be $var1 .= $var2;

Answer (score 9):

OK, because everybody is confused now

```
// _Appending_ $var2 to $var1 and assign it to $var1
$var1 .= $var2;
// _Add_ $var2 to $var1 and assign the result to $var1
$var1 += $var2;
```

There is nothing more to remember than, that *every* [binary operator is combineable with the assignment](http://php.net/anguage.operators.assignment). Within the engine it's always expanded to

```
$var1 = $var1 . $var2; // You can imagine how the others looks like
```

> In addition to the basic assignment operator, there are "combined operators" for all of the binary arithmetic, array union and string operators that allow you to use a value in an expression and then set its value to the result of that expression.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need a string formatting.

```
$var1 = sprintf( "%d%d", $var1, $var2 );
```

which will make your `$var1` as **82**.

Comment: I think his question is stated a bit confusingly; he actually doesn't want to concatenate the variables, but do mathematical calculations with them, and asks for the short notation. So although it is a very useful example, it is not the answer to his question :)

Comment: @giorgio The "problem" (is more "a little confusion") I have with this answer is, that `$var1 . $var2` just works. There is no reason for string interpolation. Thus it's not wrong (depending on what the OP _really_ wants to achieve), but (as mentioned) a little bit heavy just to append one value to another :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
$var1 = 1
$var2 = -1;

$var1 += $var2; // $var1 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Compound Assignment operators will work in php as C & Java.

you can try like this
$Var1+=$Var2;

Comment: [Reference Link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) Manual

Answer (score -1):

```
$var1=$var1-$var2;
```

will work fine, but shorthand operators like

```
$var1=-$var2
```

will not work.
I will set -2 to $var1

Notation for shorthand operator is :

```
$var1-=$var2;
```

Comment: `=-` is not one of the combined operators, but `-=` is.